# Email Verification process not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a registration page with email verification, but the verification process does not seem to work.

After typing all the user data, the user will get an email with an id and a code.

When he clicks the link, he will run through the following code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['code']))
  {
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $code=$_GET['code'];
    include("activate_user.php");
  }
?>
```

activate_user.php looks like that:

```
<?php
  include("db_connect.php");

  $sql = "select * from users where "
       . "id = " . $id
       . " and code = '" . $code . "')";

  $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);  
  $num = mysqli_num_rows($res);

  if ($num == 1)
  {
  $validate = "update users set valid = 1 where "
            . "id = " . $id
            . " and code = '" . $code . "')";

  $validate_user = mysqli_query($con, $validate);
  }

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Something must be wrong with the second php file, but I'm not sure, what the problem could be. db_connect should be fine since I'm using the same when I add the user to my database. My file is still not able to change valid from 0 to 1.

Thanks in advance for your help!

UPDATE: change mysqli_affected_row to mysqli_num_rows and added '-marks before $code, but it still doesn't work

Comment: So I guess you never heard about [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: `$code` = string/int?

Comment: `mysqli_affected_rows($res)` that is failing you. RTM on that.

Comment: @AlonEitan I already took some measures to avoid SQL injection (trim, stripslashes, htmlspecialchars), I also wanna use mysqli_real_escape_string. Would you consider that as enough protection? I know that prepared statements are the optimum right now, but I never used them before and for the moment, this should be enough.

Comment: @Fred-ii- $code is varchar, what does RTM mean?

Comment: RTM = [Read The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) ;-)

Comment: and look up "string literal mysql"

Comment: Updated my code, but it still does not work. 

FYI how $code looks. It's a 16 digit generated string consisting of numbers and letters, something like 44bdd5990df4ad25 for example. In my database it is saved as VARCHAR(16)

Comment: Not sure if it's copy & paste error but it looks like your `$validate`-query has a typo at the end. It should probably be `"')";` (single quote should be inside double quote, not outside)

Comment: @dbrumann that was just a typing error, looks different in the actual file. I fixed it

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm also not sure, if you got my response, so I'm tagging you again

Comment: best I can offer is for you to use `var_dump()` on the GETs/variables and check for errors via php's error reporting and on the query. Without knowing exactly what's going through those and the values going in db and what the db schema/values look like, I won't be of any further help.